# Como repetir o código no final no python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

então, eu estou iniciando programação (apenas por apender mesmo ) e queria saber como fazer para o código reiniciar no final.

Sei que pode parecer algo simples mas eu não faço nenhum curso, estou aprendendo sozinho

```
lanchonete = ("500$")

açaiteria = ("900$")

uber = ("200$")

pationorte = ("1200$")

pergunta = input ("Diga o nome do estabelecimento desejado ")

if pergunta ==("lanchonete"):
   print (lanchonete)

elif pergunta ==("açaiteria"):
   print (açaiteria)

elif pergunta ==("uber"):
   print (uber)

elif pergunta ==("pationorte"):
   print (pationorte)

else:
   print ("Este estabelecimento não esta cadastrado no nosso banco de 
   dados")
```

Answer (score 6):

Já que está aprendendo, vale a pena comentar. O que você fez no seu código basicamente foi relacionar quatro variáveis aos seus respectivos valores e, a princípio, não variarão durante a execução. Algo assim geralmente é chamado de mapa: você define uma relação direta entre uma chave e um valor. Neste caso, a chave seria o nome do estabelecimento e o valor a quantidade monetária relacionada. No Python, a maneira mais simples de se implementar isso é com dicionário:

```
estabelecimentos = {
    'lanchonete': '500$',
    'açaiteria': '900$',
    'uber': '200$',
    'pationorte': '1200$'
}
```

Para obter o valor a partir de uma chave, basta utilizar o método `get`, que, inclusive, permite definir um valor padrão para caso a chave não exista:

```
padrão = 'Este estabelecimento não esta cadastrado no nosso banco de dados'
pergunta = input("Diga o nome do estabelecimento desejado ")
print(estabelecimentos.get(pergunta, padrão))
```

Colocando isso dentro de um laço de repetição, ficaria:

```
estabelecimentos = {
    'lanchonete': '500$',
    'açaiteria': '900$',
    'uber': '200$',
    'pationorte': '1200$'
}

padrão = 'Este estabelecimento não esta cadastrado no nosso banco de dados'

while True:
    pergunta = input("Diga o nome do estabelecimento desejado ")
    print(estabelecimentos.get(pergunta, padrão))
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/ImmaterialBrokenArtificialintelligence)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Basta envolver seu código num loop `while True`.

O `while` verifica uma condição, e se ela for verdadeira, executa novamente tudo o que está dentro do seu bloco de indentação. Como passamos `True`, ele sempre executará tudo de novo.

Como outra dica: os parênteses são desnecessários nos casos de atribuição (`=`) e comparação (`==`), e só são necessários aqui pras funções. Seu código fica um pouco mais claro sem eles!

```
while True:
    lanchonete = "500$"

    açaiteria = "900$"

    uber = "200$"

    pationorte = "1200$"

    pergunta = input ("Diga o nome do estabelecimento desejado ")

    if pergunta == "lanchonete":
       print (lanchonete)

    elif pergunta == "açaiteria":
       print (açaiteria)

    elif pergunta == "uber":
       print (uber)

    elif pergunta == "pationorte":
       print pationorte

    else:
       print ("Este estabelecimento não esta cadastrado no nosso banco de dados")
```