# Como faço pra repetir um algoritmo em Python?

Tags: python, algoritmo

Estou começando a estudar programação e estou fazendo uma calculadora simples em Python no PyCharm, e queria saber como repetir um algoritmo quando o usuário decidir continuar a usar a calculadora. Tentei usar if e exec, mas tenho muita certeza que estou fazendo algo errado. (Ps: Teste.py é o nome do meu arquivo.)

```
print()
print()
print("-----> Calculadora <-----")
print()

valor1 = int(input("Insira o primeiro valor: "))
operação = input("Insira a operação a ser usada (+ ; -; *; /; **) ")
valor2 = int(input("Insira o segundo valor: "))

if operação == "+":
    print(valor1, " somado a ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 + valor2)

if operação == "-":
    print(valor1, " subtraindo ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 - valor2)

if operação == "*":
    print(valor1, " multiplicado por ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 * valor2)

if operação == "/":
    print(valor1, " dividido por ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 / valor2)

if operação == "**":
    print(valor1, " elevado a ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 ** valor2)

saída = input("Desejar continuar usando a calculdora? Responda sim ou não: ")
if saída == "sim":
    exec('Teste.py')
```

Comment: Você já estudou algoritmos? Estruturas de repetição?

Comment: Comecei a estudar a cadeira de algoritmos semana passada, estava realizando alguns exercícios simples e ao terminar resolvi brincar um pouco com alguns comandos pra fazer uma calculadora. Sobre estruturas de repetição só cheguei a ver algumas coisas pela internet com while, mas nada de praticar. Daí queria meio que ter uma noção básica só pra repetir esse algoritmo que acabei de fazer(não é nada sério, só estou brincando com os comandos, se for algo demais pode me ignorar kkkk).

Comment: Isso responde à sua pergunta ? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/291832/157404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque seus if's dentro de um while com uma variável condicionando o loop.

```
print()
print("-----> Calculadora <-----")
print()

loop = ""
while loop != "não":

    valor1 = int(input("Insira o primeiro valor: "))
    operação = input("Insira a operação a ser usada (+ ; -; *; /; **) ")
    valor2 = int(input("Insira o segundo valor: "))

    if operação == "+":
        print(valor1, " somado a ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 + valor2)

    if operação == "-":
        print(valor1, " subtraindo ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 - valor2)

    if operação == "*":
        print(valor1, " multiplicado por ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 * valor2)

    if operação == "/":
        print(valor1, " dividido por ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 / valor2)

    if operação == "**":
        print(valor1, " elevado a ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 ** valor2)

    loop = input("Desejar continuar usando a calculdora? Responda sim ou não: ")

print("Calculadora finalizada")
```

Answer (score 1):

Não precisa de uma variável para controlar o *loop* (como sugerido na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/449708/112052)). Você pode fazer um *loop* infinito e interrompê-lo com `break`:

```
while True:
    valor1 = int(input("Insira o primeiro valor: "))
    operação = input("Insira a operação a ser usada (+ ; -; *; /; **) ")
    valor2 = int(input("Insira o segundo valor: "))

    if operação == "+":
        print(valor1, " somado a ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 + valor2)
    elif operação == "-":
        print(valor1, " subtraindo ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 - valor2)
    elif operação == "*":
        print(valor1, " multiplicado por ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 * valor2)
    elif operação == "/":
        print(valor1, " dividido por ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 / valor2)
    elif operação == "**":
        print(valor1, " elevado a ", valor2, " é igual a ", valor1 ** valor2)

    if 'não' == input("Desejar continuar usando a calculdora? Responda sim ou não: "):
        break # sai do loop
```

Repare também que usei `elif` em vez de somente um `if`. A diferença é que se entrar em um deles, as demais condições não são testadas. Já usando somente `if` (como você estava fazendo), **todas** as alternativas serão verificadas **sempre**, o que é redundante e desnecessário (pois se entrar em uma, não precisa verificar as outras).

Para detalhar melhor, o seu código:

```
if operação == "+":
    # faz a soma

if operação == "-":
    # faz a subtração

if operação == "*":
    # faz a multiplicação
# etc...
```

Se a operação escolhida for a soma, ele entra no primeiro `if`. Só que depois ele vai testar o segundo `if`, depois vai testar o terceiro, e assim por diante. Mas se já entrou no primeiro `if`, não precisa testar os demais, pois com certeza não entrará neles.

Usando `if`/`elif` eu garanto que se entrou em uma das condições, as outras que vem depois não são mais verificadas, evitando verificações desnecessárias.

---

Repare que o código tem algumas coisas bem repetitivas: imprime os valores e faz uma operação com eles, mudando somente o texto e a operação feita.

Sendo assim, você pode generalizar, guardando as partes que variam em um dicionário (o texto e a operação feita):

```
operacoes = {
    '+': ('somado a', lambda x, y: x + y),
    '-': ('subtraindo', lambda x, y: x - y),
    '*': ('multiplicado por', lambda x, y: x * y),
    '/': ('dividido por', lambda x, y: x / y),
    '**': ('elevado a', lambda x, y: x ** y)
}

while True:
    valor1 = int(input("Insira o primeiro valor: "))
    operacao = input("Insira a operação a ser usada (+ ; -; *; /; **) ")
    valor2 = int(input("Insira o segundo valor: "))

    if operacao in operacoes:
        texto, op = operacoes[operacao]
        print(f'{valor1} {texto} {valor2} é igual a {op(valor1, valor2)}')
    else:
        print('Operação inválida')

    if 'não' == input("Desejar continuar usando a calculdora? Responda sim ou não: "):
        break
```

O dicionário `operacoes` mapeia cada operação (`+`, `-`, etc) com seu respectivo texto e com a conta a ser feita com os números (ambos guardados em uma tupla).

Dentro do *loop* basta verificar se a operação digitada existe no dicionário, e caso exista, use o texto e a respectiva conta para exibir o resultado.

---

Para as operações aritméticas, uma opção para não criar *lambdas* é usar o [módulo `operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions):

```
from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv, pow

operacoes = {
    '+': ('somado a', add),
    '-': ('subtraindo', sub),
    '*': ('multiplicado por', mul),
    '/': ('dividido por', truediv),
    '**': ('elevado a', pow)
}

# restante do código igual
```